# Separa callback de mi código para reutilizar

Tags: typescript, callback

Tengo el siguiente código como servicio:

```js
   findById_multiple(ids: string[]): Observable<Proceso[]> {
       let a = this._preLoaderService.loading("Buscando procesos por defecto")
       let i = { busqueda: ids }
       return this.http.post(`${this.base}/buscar_multiple`, i).pipe(
         map((resp: any,) => {
         let p: Proceso[] = []
         resp.procesos.forEach((pp) => {
           let np = new Proceso().deserialize(pp)
           p.push(np)
         })
         this._msjService.ok_(a)

         return p
       }),
         catchError(this.err)
       )
     }
```

Me gustaría extraer el callback que tengo dentro de `map`para reutilizarlo por que este código se repite. El problema es que no encuentro la manera de pasar al callback el parametro `a` que genero y que despues utilizo  en la linea `this._msjService.ok_(a)`.

Hay manera de lograr esto sin que a se aplique `a` a toda la clase?